# Rust Analyser Update VS Code

Tags: rust, task, analyzer

After updating the Rust Analyser extension, tasks stopped working.

My Rust Analyser configuration is the following:

```json
{
    "type": "cargo",
    "command": "build",
    "problemMatcher": [
        "$rustc"
    ],
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
    },
    "label": "rust: cargo build debug all"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the task format slightly to:

```json
{
    "type": "process",
    "command": "cargo",
    "args": [
        "build"
    ],
    "problemMatcher": [
        "$rustc"
    ],
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
    },
    "label": "rust: cargo build debug all"
}
```

Essentially changing the task type from `"cargo"` to `"process"`, the command from `"build"` to `"cargo"` and moving the build command into the arguments section.